# Raspberry Pi 4 Running Ubuntu 64 - mouse lag

Tags: mouse, raspberrypi

This problem is so bad that I dread using my otherwise great setup.

The problem is that my wireless mouse is very laggy. It is especially hard to accurately move the mouse to a specific spot since it will overshoot and need to be carefully positioned.

I've found tips on how to fix this problem but they seem to only apply to the standard Debian 32 installs, not Ubuntu.

Here is one example: https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/fix-that-laggy-wifi-mouse

Has anyone looked at this problem for Ubuntu 64?

Appreciate your help!
-Demetri

Comment: Does this happen on a fresh install? Which Pi are you using? Which mouse? I have installed Ubuntu on a Pi 4 and the wireless mouse worked fine. My only issue was it couldn't play back fullscreen video without overheating.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 64 version. Can you [edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a` so we know the version of your OS?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem. Here was my solution using a wifi/wireless mouse.

```
sudo nano /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt
```

add  `usbhid.mousepoll=8` to the end of the line (without the quotes).

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
reboot
```

problem solved

If there is still some input lag, try plugging the mouse dongle into a usb hub using one of the usb 3.0 ports. Happy computing!

Comment: tried multiple other suggestions (/etc/modules, /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf, ..) THIS finally worked on Raspberry Pi 4, Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: I also worked on Raspberry Pi 5, Ubuntu 23.10